# DBLink from SQL Server to postgresql: get sequence nextval

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, rpc, dblink

I've got a SQL Server 2008 that needs to connect to a POSTGRESQL 9.0 server.

One of the tasks that i need is to get the next value of a sequence over the POSTGRESQL

**Example 1 :**

```
execute ('select nextval( ''cadastro.pessoa_seq'' )' ) at POSTGRESQL ;
```

error:

> Msg 7215, Level 17, State 1, Line 1 Could not execute statement on
>   remote server 'POSTGRESQL'.*

**Example 2 :**

```
select * from openquery( POSTGRESQL ,'select nextval( ''cadastro.pessoa_seq'' )')
```

error:

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for
>   linked server "POSTGRESQL" reported an error. The provider reported an
>   unexpected catastrophic failure. Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for
>   linked server "POSTGRESQL".*

None of these options works!

Is there any good alternative ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What exactly does "none works" mean? Do you get an error? If yes, from which DBMS?

Comment: I did an update to the post. i get the error in SQLSERVER . TIA

Comment: Are you able to use the connection for other queries?  Is it just sequences you're having problems with?

Comment: Yes, i can execute "Select * From [...]" ! I'm having troubles with exectuing remote functions, sequences...!

Answer (score 1):

dealing with ODBC sources and postgres I have to do this:

```
nextval(''cadastro.pessoa_seq''::regclass) for it to work
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your Postgresql connection is readonly , have you tried to execute an update/insert request ?

nextval update the sequence , try:

```
currval(''cadastro.pessoa_seq''::regclass)
```